# java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate, MySQL connection is valid  but I get the following.
How do I see more details on connection string that it's connecting to?

```
ERROR SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        ... 10 more
ERROR SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        ... 10 more

ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:342)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        ... 18 more
```

here's my hibernate xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxxx</property>

        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">200</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">200</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Is this happening on every operation or just some times?

Comment: @AmitChotaliya it happens all the time, I can connect to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test and jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test without issue at command line, ports are open

Comment: Okay, I asked that because this happens when you max out connections. i.e in c3p0 you have 200 connection allowed but mysql default max 151, so if it tries to acquire after that then you'd get this error.

Comment: Probably your getting root@localhost login fail, check you database if have user with roo@localhost and not root@%

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was problem that c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar file was not copied by maven into `src/main/webapp/web-inf/libs`

Answer (score 4):

I will recommend two things to get this problem resolved :
First, try mentioning your database name in capital letters. Though db is case insensitive still , sometimes it runs fine with caps.

Secondly , this problem may arise because of some extra stuff you might have appended with your session factory value. For example (i will take code i used and faced this problem and the got rid of it) : 
Part of my xml goes like this :

```
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://10.184.56.183:3306/******?relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
    <property name="connection.username">******</property>
    <property name="connection.password">******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">108000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
```

So keep trimming extra values like clean your database connection url and other stuff. I faced problem while generating code from database table as well. So i created a different config xml and made that as simple as possible and thats it. It went very fine .

Answer (score 4):

I solved this challange by following [Confluence Support](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/connections-could-not-be-acquired-from-the-underlying-database-104825087.html) article.

The Causes and Resolutions as stated by the above blog post for the issue of
**`cannot establish a connection to its database.`** are

1. **The database configuration details you entered are incorrect or have
   changed.** For example, the database name or database
   username/password for your Confluence database. Confirm that the
   database username, password, and connection URL in
   /confluence.cfg.xml are incorrect, and if not
   update them accordingly.
2. **The URL for the database is incorrect.** 
   For example, if the database connection is  jdbc:mysql://yma/confluence?autoReconnect=true, does the host 'yma'
   exist and is the database server installed on 'yma'? Check
   /confluence.cfg.xml to find this entry.
       The database server is not running. If your database server is down, restart it and check the logs to see why it had failed or
   stopped.
3. **The network is down (or there is a firewall in between Confluence and its database) and the connection to the database**
   cannot be established. If your network is down, or a new firewall is
   installed, consult with your System Administrator for further
   troubleshooting.
4. **Your database password has expired.** 
   If your password has expired (and you will only discover this if you try to connect to your
   database via your database client or an external database tool such
   as DbVisualizer), update your password. You may want to deactivate
   expiring passwords for your Confluence database user to prevent the
   problem from happening again. Be sure to consult with your DBA about
   this.
5. **Postgres specific issue:** the Postgres encryption method has been altered or changed when migrating or upgrading Confluence, the
   environment, etc. Check the pg_hba.conf file. If the method is set
   to ident change it to md5.
6. **MySQL specific issue:** there are too many connection requests that triggered MySQL server to block Confluence from making any
   requests. See this MySQL article for resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and the issue was our office IP address being blocked by MySQL server due to many connect attempts using bad credentials.

Make sure you can connect to the server using the same method/network as your application. If you get this or something like this when attempting to connect using some MySQL client (like Workbench)

```
Host 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.static.XXXXXX.XXX' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

Your IP is blocked and that is the issue.